# Question-answering dataset about home appliance

Tags: data-request

People tend to ask many questions about home appliance devices, e.g. washing machines:

- how to use it
- how to troubleshoot possible failures when using it

This information is scattered across many forums, support Websites, etc.

Is there any dataset with questions and answers collected together? Maybe there was a research paper using it for a question-answering competition?